# i am not getting error during compile time but when i run the program i get error

Tags: java

I am writing a program in java to count number of constants and vowels and i am getting this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 26
        at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
        at B.main(B.java:17)" what should i do?

[programcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80OoB.png)

[cmd output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdINW.png)

Comment: Instead of posting pictures of code, please post the actual code and error in the question.

Answer (score 2):

In java string index starts from `0`. So you should use `i < str.length()` not `i <= str.length()`.
example:

```
String str = "a really, really long string";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
}
```

And there's no need of importing the classes in `java.lang` package since all of them are already imported by the jvm by default.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the loop from i = 0 to i < str.length or i<=str.length-1
As the final iteration is for str.length it goes out of index.... because the length of str is from 0 to length-1.

```
for (i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
    //TODO your code here.
}
```